# Does Ph.D. research count as "academic projects" and/or "professional work experience"

Tags: applications, work-experience, research

I think the title says it all. I'm filling out a job application that asks

> How many years of experience do you have in an engineering related field, including: academic projects, internships, or professional work experience?

If we are only counting internship-wise, I have 2 years of experience, but with Ph.D. research I have 6 years. Thoughts?

I'm getting a Ph.D. and doing my research in Mechanical Engineering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the application states:

> How many years of experience do have you have in an engineering related field, including: **academic projects**, internships, or professional work experience?

Ph.D research can be considered as "academic projects". Plus, you mention it was on Mechanical Engineering, so definitely would be a good candidate as valid work experience in an engineering related field. Therefore, I see no problem with you including that in your application, good luck with your job searching process.